# How to force interface generic type to implement a generic interface?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the interface implementations below:

```
public interface IIdempotencyKey<out TKey>
{
   string GetHash();
   IEnumerable<string> GetKeyParts();
   TKey Key { get; }
}

public classs DepositIdempotencyKey : IIdempotencyKey<Guid>
{
   public Guid Key { get; }
   ...
}

public interface IGrainCommand<TIdempotencyKey>
{
   TIdempotencyKey IdempotencyKey { get; }
}

public class DepositCommand : IGrainCommand<DepositIdempotencyKey>
{
  public DepositIdempotencyKey { get; }
  ...
}
```

How can I guarantee that the generic type `IGrainCommand<DepositIdempotencyKey>` on `DepositCommand` is a `IIdempotencyKey<TKey>` ? Is there a better way to model this?

Comment: `public interface IGrainCommand<TIdempotencyKey, out TKey> where TIdempotencyKey : IIdempotencyKey<TKey>` maybe?

Comment: @Charlieface the problem is that I have to specify the TKey twice, one in DepositIdempotencyKey and the same type in DepositCommand.

Answer (score 2):

Charlieface's comment is basically correct:

```cs
public interface IIdempotencyKey<out TKey>
{
   TKey Key { get; }
}

public class DepositIdempotencyKey : IIdempotencyKey<Guid>
{
   public Guid Key { get; }
}

public interface IGrainCommand<TIdempotencyKey, TKey> where TIdempotencyKey : IIdempotencyKey<TKey>
{
   TIdempotencyKey IdempotencyKey { get; }
}

public class DepositCommand : IGrainCommand<DepositIdempotencyKey, Guid>
{
  public DepositIdempotencyKey IdempotencyKey { get; }
}
```

The `where` restricts the possible values of `TIdempotencyKey`, but the trade off is that you will have to specify the type of `TKey` also.

The one change I've made to his suggestion is to remove the `out` from `TKey` on `IGrainCommand<TIdempotencyKey, TKey>` as I'm not sure what it adds, unless you want to be able to implement this interface with a more generic value for `TKey` than the implementation of `IIdempotencyKey`.

**UPDATE:**
To answer your comment, you could avoid the need for specifying `TKey` again given that you don't use it in `DepositCommand` - by defining a non-generic `IIdempotencyKey` from which the generic `IIdempotencyKey<out TKey` inherits:

```cs
public interface IIdempotencyKey {}

public interface IIdempotencyKey<out TKey> : IIdempotencyKey
{
   TKey Key { get; }
}

public class DepositIdempotencyKey : IIdempotencyKey<Guid>
{
   public Guid Key { get; }
}

public interface IGrainCommand<TIdempotencyKey> where TIdempotencyKey : IIdempotencyKey
{
   TIdempotencyKey IdempotencyKey { get; }
}

public class DepositCommand : IGrainCommand<DepositIdempotencyKey>
{
  public DepositIdempotencyKey IdempotencyKey { get; }
}
```

I think it's worth calling out here that it's the `IGrainCommand` interface declaration that needs to know exactly what type you're constraining `TIdempotencyKey` to - yes `DepositCommand` can infer that `TKey` is a `Guid`, but the interface cannot, so you need to be explicit if you're going to access `IdempotencyKey.Key` inside the interface. If you only need to access it inside `DepositCommand` then the final type of `IdempotencyKey` is known so `IdempotencyKey.Key` can be used with no further constraint, and using the non-generic `IIdempotencyKey` as a marker for constraining `TIdempotencyKey` is sufficient.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I guess I assumed if `IIdempotencyKey<out TKey>` then `IGrainCommand` should also be `out TKey`.

Comment: Is there any way that I doesn't need to specify the TKey twice (in command and in the key implementation) ?

Comment: See my comment. I think you're probably hoping for a more elegant solution, which unfortunately doesn't exist to my knowledge.

Comment: Should have said "see my update"...